# google cloud spanner upsert only support primary key

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

Hope you are enjoying the holiday season.

I'm trying to migrating some upsert code piece from mysql into spanner, but somehow spanner only supports upsert on primary key, not unique key as secondary index.

mysql example:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(45),
    ssn varchar(15),
    CONSTRAINT uc_ssn Unique(ssn)
);


INSERT INTO table (id,name,ssn)
VALUES (1,'a', '111-111-1111')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE name=name;

# below insert should update name into 'b' due to uc_ssn constraint and on duplicate key update.
INSERT INTO table (id,name,ssn)
VALUES (2,'b', '111-111-1111')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE name=name;
```

However in spanner, similar change using `Mutation.newInsertOrUpdateBuilder` reports unique key violation.
google support states that upsert could only use primary key for duplicate check.
since id is different, spanner takes it as new record, hence fails to insert it due to unique key constraint from secondary key.

Our code is currently running on mysql, which supports on duplicate key update with unique constraint.
Since Spanner doesn't support the same, I see 2 options:

1. create id from sha256(columns in secondary unique key), then use id(primary key) for upsert.
2. within read consistent transaction: query for existence of record with unique key, if exists, use update, otherwise, try insert.
   I'm feeling option 1 is simpler, is there any catch.  sha256 has 2^256 possible value, so change of collision should be extremely unlikely.
   Option 2 seems a bit complicated for a simple upsert, I'm wondering it may run slower.

any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Generating a primary key from the unique constraint values: This will certainly be the fastest and simplest solution. There is a theoretical possibility that you could have a key collision, but that is more theoretical than a real problem. So based only on the information in this question, I would have chosen this.
2. Executing a `SELECT` to check for the existence of a record first will be much slower than alternative 1.

**Alternative**:

Have you considered making `ssn` the primary key? I know that it would mean that you are making a primary key that contains a meaningful value. But if you choose to generate a primary key from the `ssn`, then you are partially doing that already.

I think that one important reason **not** to make `ssn` the primary key would be if you are going to reference the `person` table from any other table. That would mean that you would have `ssn` values spread around in different tables in your database, which you probably don't want.

Comment: thanks heaps for your answer. I'm only using the simple table as example.  In our real-life use case, the secondary unique index is combination of multiple columns, so using them as primary key can be awkward.

Comment: after further reading, I'm planning to use the composite unique key as primary key, since the composite key is not used from other table.